# How to map table fields from source as the variables of stored procedure in destination in SSIS Package?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssis

I want to transfer data from source Database table named **Patient** (which contains many rows) to destination database tables(2) named **Person** & **Patient**.

I already have stored procedure named **AddPatient** in destination database which will add person related fields to **Person** table and other fields to **Patient** table, so I would like to execute that procedure and to assign the fields from source database as variables to it. The following are the code of **AddPatient** sp in destination database.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddPatient]    
(  
@TenantId BIGINT,  
@FirstName  NVARCHAR(100),  
@LastName NVARCHAR(100),  
@PersonNumber NVARCHAR(20),  
@MobileNumber NVARCHAR(20),  
@EmailId NVARCHAR(100),  
@Address NVARCHAR(255),  
@City NVARCHAR(50),  
@ZipCode NVARCHAR(20),  
@ListComments NVARCHAR(1000),  
@Comment NVARCHAR(500),  
@AlternateEmailId NVARCHAR(100) ,  
@HomePhone NVARCHAR(20) ,  
@Relative NVARCHAR(255) ,  
@HasDiabetes [bit],  
@HasBlooPressure [bit],   
@AddedBy BIGINT,  
@AddedDateTime smalldatetime,
@PersonId BIGINT OUTPUT
)  
AS   
BEGIN   
 SET NOCOUNT ON     
IF @TenantId IS NULL   
  RAISERROR('The value for @TenantID should not be null', 15, 1) -- with log  
ELSE  
BEGIN  
 DECLARE @new_person_id BIGINT  
 DECLARE @new_patient_id BIGINT  
 DECLARE @PatientIdentifier NVARCHAR(50)  
 EXEC dbo.GetNextPatientIdForTenant @TenantID, @PatientIdentifier OUTPUT  
 INSERT INTO dbo.Person    
      (                   
TenantId,  
FirstName,  
LastName,     
PersonNumber,  
MobileNumber,  
EmailId,  
Address,  
City,  
ZipCode,    
AddedBy,
AddedDateTime                                      
      )     
 VALUES     
      (     
       @TenantId,  
@FirstName,  
@LastName,    
@PersonNumber,  
@MobileNumber,  
@EmailId,  
@Address,  
@City,  
@ZipCode,    
@AddedBy,
@AddedDateTime                    
      )     
SELECT @new_person_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()  

INSERT INTO dbo.Patient    
      (     
TenantId,  
PatientIdentifier,  
PersonId,    
ListComments,  
Comment,  
AlternateEmailId,  
HomePhone,  
Relative,     
HasDiabetes,     
HasBlooPressure,    
AddedBy,      
AddedDateTime                                             
      )     
 VALUES     
      (     
@TenantId,  
@PatientIdentifier,  
@new_person_id,   
@ListComments ,  
@Comment ,  
@AlternateEmailId,  
@HomePhone ,  
@Relative ,    
@HasDiabetes,  
@HasBlooPressure,   
@AddedBy ,  
@AddedDateTime         
      )     
SELECT @new_patient_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()  
SELECT @PersonId = @new_person_id
SELECT @new_patient_id         
END     
END
```

There is no *TenantId* & *AddedBy* field in source, so I want to assign both as **1** for all rows to be transfered.

I know **Execute SQL Task** will handles stored procedure and for each row data **Foreach Loop Container** will take care in **SSIS**. But I don't know how to assign the variables of sp in destination database to the fields of table from source database.

Anyone help me with this.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Executing `SP` in the destination component is not the right way to do it. The SP will be executed for `each and every row`. It will be better if you can post your SP code so that the inserting can be a `set based` operation

Comment: @praveen :     **AddPatient** sp is designed to insert a row data in both tables *Person* & *Patient*, but my SSIS requirement is to insert all rows from source to this destination that's y I would like to run this sp of destination database in **Foreach loop container**. To be clear, destination is newly designed database for the new product, now my task is to transfer old data (thousands of rows) from my client's old database(source) which has entirely different database structures. If u want to view my **AddPatient** sp code ? Reply me, then I'll update the question with that.

Comment: It will be better if you can show the SP code

Comment: @praveen:      now u can have a look over the question with the SP code.

Comment: You can use `oledb command` inside `Data flow task` just after your source component and the map the column .Check this [Link](http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/OLE-DB-Command-Transformation.aspx). Does the SP `GetNextPatientIdForTenant ` always return the same value as your passing constant TenantID which is `1`

Comment: @praveen:      I did what you said. I have entered **Exec AddPatient** in Component properties tab in OLE DB Command and even refreshed. but i didn't got any columns in *Available Destination Columns*. what about the **TenantId** and **AddedBy** columns which I have to assign the value **1** ? But even I ran the package, I got an error due to *TenantId*.

Comment: @praveen:      Error :-  **[OLE DB Command [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E10.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E10  Description: "Procedure or function 'AddPatient' expects parameter '@TenantId', which was not supplied.".**

Comment: You need to add `Derived transformation` after the source component and create 2 new columns `TenantID and AddedBy` and write `1` in the expression and then in the OLEDB map the above 2 columns

Comment: @praveen:      Even I did that too. But I got the newly added columns in **Available Input Columns** but nothing in **Available Destination Columns**, so I can't able to map the columns.

Comment: @praveen:      I think due to adding "exec AddPatient" as sql command in OLE DB Command editor, so I didn't get any columns as destination in **Available Destination Columns**. Am I correct?

Comment: Try to click on `Refresh` in `Oledb command Editor` or you may not be having the column in the SP itself

Comment: Try adding `SET FMTONLY OFF` to your SP I have found that sometimes SSIS doesn't pickup on the metadata correctly, this tends to force it to give an output.

Comment: @praveen:   Mistake is mine. Now I getting the destination columns in **Available Destination Columns** after re-typed sql command "exec AddPatient ?,?,? etc.,." for total variables in sp instead of "exec AddPatient",after it shows all destination columns and I mapped the columns. But I got an error stating that **Error code: 0x80040E21-Invalid character value for cast specification**. I think it's due to an output parameter in sp, because I didn't mapped this column & **?** in sql command. Before that I resolved the errors one by one by adding **?** in sql comm, then oly i got the above error

Comment: @Peter_R:     Even I had added **SET FMTONLY OFF** in my sp, I got an error (stated in the above comment for praveen). What I have to do to resolve this(I think the error due to output parameter not mapped in **Column mappings** tab in OLE DB Command)?

Comment: @Peter_R:      I came to know that **SET FMTONLY** is OFF by default, in this link http://munishbansal.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/set-fmtonly-on-useful-in-tsql-ssis-packages-for-using-temp-tables/ I think then there is no need to define like this *SET FMTONLY OFF* and for more info about *SET FMTONLY* look here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e04bb4a2-ba07-4ec1-b3d6-f30125fa73c0/dynamic-sql-in-stored-procedure-and-error-with-set-fmtonly

Comment: @praveen:      will u please help me to resolve the above error **Error code: 0x80040E21-Invalid character value for cast specification** ?

Comment: @Prakash :  Use a `Data Viewer` just before the destination and check which column value has data type issue. My guess is, there might be some blank values for the input columns `HasDiabetes and HasBlooPressure`  or the data type for `AddedDateTime` may not be in the correct date time format.

Comment: @praveen:      Just now myself resolved the error, without noticed ur recent comment. Mistake is on **DOB Date** in sp which is not included in sp shown in the question but available in real sp.I had given **" "** (string format) in derived column for DOB (because DOB is not available in source table) and mapped it to the destination column, then I noticed that and changed it to **GetDate()** in the expression. Then another error came stating about the output parameter *PersonId* is not passed, then I added that too in derived col. thus **I got the output** (data trans. as I want).

Comment: @praveen:      Assigning current date to *DOB* is not logic, so Is there any way to assign **NULL** for *DOB Date* as database timestamp instead of *GETDATE()*  in the expression ?

Comment: @Prakash : Instead of `GETDATE()` use `NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)`

Comment: @praveen:      thanks. its works fine for timestamp, but I tried for string like **NULL(DT_WSTR)**, it shows an error **Attempt to parse the expression "NULL(DT_WSTR)" failed.** what shall I do for *string* and *int*?

Comment: You have to specify the length for the string like `NULL(DT_WSTR,50)`

Comment: @praveen:      thanks. I had given like this **NULL(DT_WSTR,0)** because its only *NULL* and it works fine.

Comment: @Prakash, can you add your answer here. It will help others too

Comment: @Billa:        I already had a plan to do that. I will post the answer when I get time.